# Shortcut Keys do not work any more

Tags: itunes, windows

Previously when editing the information about a song, you could press Alt+G to go to the Genre, or Alt+A to the artist.

This seems to not work in the latest iTunes 12.

Is there a way to get the shortcut keys back?

Comment: Help > Keyboard shortcuts might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that feature has been taken off.
While not exactly the answer, CMD-I shows information about the selected song or disk. A workaround could be sort by Artist or Genre

Comment: IMO, that was a ridiculous decision to take away shortcuts. Very irritating